# How do I select multiple SQL tables in my DataTable grid in C# to display them in the UI via a query?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

```
private DataTable Getvalue(SqlConnection conn, int contentId)
        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"
                    SELECT
                          S.[Item_ID]
                        , S.[Item]
                        , S.[Description]
                    FROM dbo.Company_Items S
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.Company_StoreItems D
                            ON D.[Item_ID] = S.[Item_ID]
                            AND D.[Content_ID] = @Content_ID
                    WHERE S.[Valid] = 1 
                    ORDER BY S.[Item]";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Content_ID", contentId);
                return Fill(cmd, InitvalueTable);
            }
        }
```

This data table will populate my UI with tables existing in the Items table. In the same tab, I also want to add other pieces of information from other tables, for example

```
ItemPrice from table dbo.Company_ItemInfo 

PurchaseDate from table dbo_Company_Purchases
```

How would I add those column inside the query listed above? Can I have 2 FROMs? I am losing myself in the syntax.

Comment: What are the schema of the three tables? Do they have joinable fields?

Comment: dbo.something looks like this is a sql server script and not mysql

Answer (score 1):

you can use UNION for multiple selects.

```
SELECT a.name as name, a.type as type, a.location as location, '' as price from TableA a
UNION
SELECT '' as name, b.type, b.location, b.price from TableB b
ORDER BY price;
```

for you code, example:

```
SELECT S.[Item_ID] , S.[Item] , S.[Description] 
    FROM dbo.Company_Items S 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Company_StoreItems D ON D.[Item_ID] = S.[Item_ID] AND D.[Content_ID] = @Content_ID 
    WHERE S.[Valid] = 1 
    
UNION 

SELECT S.[Item_ID] , S.[Item] , S.[Description] 
    FROM dbo.Company_Items S 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Company_StoreItems D ON D.[Item_ID] = S.[Item_ID] AND D.[Content_ID] = @Content_ID 
    WHERE S.[Valid] = 1 
    
ORDER BY Item
```

Comment: Thanks. but this gives me a syntax error
 [code]
SELECT
                          S.[Item_ID]
                        , S.[Item]
                        , S.[Description]
                    FROM dbo.Company_Items S
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.Company_StoreItems D
                            ON D.[Item_ID] = S.[Item_ID]
                            AND D.[Content_ID] = @Content_ID
                    WHERE S.[Valid] = 1 
                    ORDER BY S.[Item]
                    UNION
                    SELECT 
[code]

at the UNION keyword

Comment: if you use MYSQL, check this reference for union: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: the error is in the order by statement, it must be placed at the end of the union of all tables

Comment: There's also `union all` which won't do a distinct like `union`